# Html not Relation symbol for letter R

Tags: html, latex, symbols

How can the following image be written in latex or html?

[image]

(*a is not in relation to b*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write here three basic solutions: of course they may all be improved, we could go deeper if they rise some interest.

---

**1) LaTeX**

A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) may be the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
a\not\mathrel{R} b
\]
\end{document}
```

Further, the [`centernot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) package may be recommended.

---

**2) HTML5 + MathJax**

Copy and paste the following into filename.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>a is not in relation with b</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
\[
a\not\mathrel{R} b
\]
</body>
</html>
```

---

**3) HTML5 + CSS** ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qdbwdjv/))

This would instead be an *inline math* approach:

```css
.notrel {
  display:inline-block;
  width:.6em;
  text-align:center;
  font-style:italic;
  letter-spacing:-0.5em;
}
```

```html
a <span class="notrel">/R</span> b
```

Comment: Great. The problem with MathJax is that if you write some content it breaks line, unless you write everything in Mathjax tags

Comment: Also another  cheap solution is to use an image :)

Comment: @GragasIncoming Glad it helped! Ok about the image (try https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php). In MathJax you can do both inline and displayed math...